# What do I have to do to get Pair Hero to work?

Tags: eclipse, plugins

I'm attempting to setup [Pair Hero](http://www.happyprog.com/pairhero/) in my Eclipse install. It installed fine, and I'm able to add players, but I can't figure out how to tell it to switch, or how it can tell when tests are run, etc. I don't see any documentation. Has anyone used it?

It may be worth noting that I'm using a customized version of Eclipse -- [CFBuilder](http://www.adobe.com/go/cfbuilder) -- to write ColdFusion, JavaScript, and various other code languages; not Java. I don't see any indication on the Pair Hero site that it only works for Java, but then again, there's not any real direction on how to play at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pair Hero "hooks" into the JUnit Core framework of Eclipse. It works with any language that uses JUnit to run the tests. I have used it with Java, Groovy and someone told me that it works with Scala as well.

I know of someone else reporting that it doesn't work with MXUnit. I am not sure if MXUnit ends up delegating to JUnit. I quickly looked at the source and could not draw a clear conclusion but most likely that it is not since Pair Hero would have caught those calls.

Comment: I don't think MXUnit does any integration with JUnit, so I'm pretty much out of luck. Thanks.